# How to redirect Entire Wordpress site to a new Domain Using Ht access

Tags: wordpress

I just Move to A new Doamin
www.9jabaz.com
SO i am using this ht access code

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
Redirect 301 / http://9jabaz.com/
</IfModule>
# End Wordpress
```

So it redirects People from 9jabaz.com.ng to 9jabaz.com...It works Very Fine..

But is is possible Not To redirect The Wp-admin??
Any idea

`

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/669029/using-htaccess-to-redirect-from-one-domain-to-another

Comment: nothing is there help pls